# How do I update BIOS on a computer that doesn't boot

Tags: ubuntu, usb, bios

So I have encountered the issue on my Matebook X Pro that is running Ubuntu 18.04 where I restarted it but it will not boot. It turns on, flashes the Huawei logo then after a second turns off. This repeats in an endless cycle.

I read on reddit that lots of users experience this problem and the solution is to update BIOS.

The problem is that I have already downloaded the zip file (containing the updated BIOS) onto my flash drive, but the computer does not see the USB. When i press ctrl+alt+F1, I am taken to the Insydeh20 setup utility. Under bootable devices it lists my SSD. When I disable the SSD with the USB plugged in, it says no bootable device found, so I cannot use the USB to run the zip file. Any suggestions as to what I can do? The device doesn't boot up at all, not even until to Ubuntu loading screen.

Edit:
It turns out there USB has to be reformatted first, but I am away from home for 3 weeks and the only USB I have contains important work files. Is there anything else I can do? I don't think an outdated BIOS is that big of a problem? Can I bypass this boot loop without updating the BIOS? I was thinking of updating it later.

Edit:
I could not find any guide on how to format my USB so that the computer can see it from the BIOS menu and update BIOS straight away. Right now my USB is not formatted in any special way so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the USB bootable? Have you tried booting a different machine from it?

Comment: @choroba I haven't tried booting a different machine as the only other working machine belongs to someone else and I don't want to mees it up. The USB works fine with storing and transferring files though

Comment: Just putting the zip file on an USB stick won't work. You have to create an USB stick in a special format (google, there are various ways to do that, and various tools).

Comment: @dirkt oh right, all the guides I was following didn't say anything about formatting the stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I have solved the issue and I really hope that anyone who has it can benefit from my answer.

All I had to do was to go into BIOS (ctrl, alt, f2) then disable secure boot that is enabled by default. Then it all booted up and none of my data was lost. Thank you to everyone who tried to help